# ccny_vision: Oneiric compile-error (glut related)

Tags: ubuntu-oneiric, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This compile error has nothing to do with the videodev.h includes for which a patch still works on Ubuntu Oneiric (11.10).

Also I manually patched robot_model/ivcon/CMakeLists.txt to build in Oneiric, as per: https://kforge.ros.org/robotmodel/robot_model/rev/ca7f1a0f1a58

The problem I can't fix is that ar_pose won't build due to some linking error related to glut. I suspect this error may be related to the libglut --> freeglut change in Oneiric, since the error did not crop up in either Debian Squeeze (amd64) or Ubuntu Natty (armel). Perhaps some compile flags would fix this. Build error context:

```
  gsub.c:(.text+0x2e4b): undefined reference to `glVertex2f'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x2e50): undefined reference to `glEnd'
  /home/joris/ros/stacks/ccny_vision/artoolkit/lib/libARgsub.a(gsub.o): In function `argInit':
  gsub.c:(.text+0x3018): undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x3027): undefined reference to `glutInitWindowPosition'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x3038): undefined reference to `glutInitWindowSize'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x3042): undefined reference to `glutCreateWindow'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x3051): undefined reference to `glutFullScreen'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x305b): undefined reference to `glutGet'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x306b): undefined reference to `glutGet'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x30a1): undefined reference to `glGenTextures'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x30b1): undefined reference to `glBindTexture'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x30c0): undefined reference to `glPixelStorei'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x30d7): undefined reference to `glTexParameterf'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x30ee): undefined reference to `glTexParameterf'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x3105): undefined reference to `glTexParameterf'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x311c): undefined reference to `glTexParameterf'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x3133): undefined reference to `glTexEnvf'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x3143): undefined reference to `glBindTexture'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x3152): undefined reference to `glPixelStorei'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x3169): undefined reference to `glTexParameterf'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x3180): undefined reference to `glTexParameterf'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x3197): undefined reference to `glTexParameterf'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x31ae): undefined reference to `glTexParameterf'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x31c5): undefined reference to `glTexEnvf'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x31d5): undefined reference to `glBindTexture'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x31e4): undefined reference to `glPixelStorei'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x31fb): undefined reference to `glTexParameterf'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x3212): undefined reference to `glTexParameterf'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x3229): undefined reference to `glTexParameterf'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x3240): undefined reference to `glTexParameterf'
  gsub.c:(.text+0x3257): undefined reference to `glTexEnvf'
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[3]: *** [../bin/ar_multi] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/joris/ros/stacks/ccny_vision/ar_pose/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ar_multi.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/joris/ros/stacks/ccny_vision/ar_pose/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/joris/ros/stacks/ccny_vision/ar_pose/build'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11693/ccny_vision:-oneiric-compile-error-(glut-related)/) by [Joris](https://answers.ros.org/users/973/joris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2011-10-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The new linker coming with Ubuntu Oneiric is less tolerant regarding the order of linker flags than previous versions.

A quick and dirty way to have ar_pose compile & link is to run this command in the ar_pose directory:

`sed '/^#rosbuild_gensrv\(\)/a set\(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS -Wl,--no-as-needed\)' -i CMakeLists.txt`

---

Originally posted by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) with karma: 916 on 2011-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2011-11-29**:
works for me. thanks a lot!